# Render async data, retrived from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am fetching data from my firebase database in componentDidMount method.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    firebase.database().ref('posts').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        this.setState({
            posts: snapshot.val()
        })
    })
}
```

I want use this data in my render method. The problem is - when the render method executes, my state is not updated yet, because its async and the state is null. 
How can I render my data after state changes and i will have my data in my state ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering data from Firebase in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497606/rendering-data-from-firebase-in-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before data is retrieved posts field in state is null. Then posts is set and render is called again. You can do something like this:

```
render(){
   if (!this.state.posts){
      return <div>Loading</div>;
   }

   return <div>Render your posts here...</div>
}
```